# How CPUQuota works in systemd

Tags: systemd, cpu-usage

I'm setting up a `.slice` file for systemd. I want to restrict the slice to a certain amount of CPU time. But it's not clear to me from [the systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) whether the percentage given to the `CPUQuota` is interpreted as a number of cores or a fraction of the whole system.

To get specific: My computer has 36 cores. If I want to restrict the slice to 9 of them (1/4 of the system's capacity), do I want `CPUQuota:25%` or `CPUQuota:900%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CPUQuota=900%` per  man [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#CPUQuota=)